# Getting the index of a dropdown array on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select, dropdown

I have multiple dropdowns and they are named like this:
`pricing[1], pricing[2], pricing[3]` and so on.
`onchange` event of every dropdown named `pricing[]`, I would like to get the index of the `pricing[x]`, which is 'x' in that case, as well as the selected value.

HTML:

```
foreach($allindichapter as $chapter){
    echo "<select name='pricing[".$chapter['CHAPTER']."]' id='pricing[".$chapter['CHAPTER']."]' class='pricing' style='width:100%'>";

foreach($indimonthly as $imchapter => $type){
        foreach($type as $typ => $price){
            if($imchapter == $chapter['CHAPTER'])
                echo '<option value="'.$chapter.'">Monthly - '.$price.'Php</option>';
            break;
        }
    }
echo "</select>";
}
```

The problem is, I cannot even enter the `onchange` function for the dropdown. I have tried different ways such as:

```
$('select').change(function(){
            console.log($('option:selected',this).index()); 
        });

$(function(){
        $('select').change(function(){
            console.log($('option:selected',this).index()); 
        });

$('.pricing').bind("change",function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(id);
            });`
```

I have also used the `onchange="pricechange()"` with a JQuery function.
Any help will be appreciated.

For reference, this is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

When the Pricing is changed, I will update the Duration dropdown.

Comment: If none of those work, you're going to have to post the HTML as well, and explain how you've created those selects

Comment: Thank you. I have added the full code of how I've created the dropdowns.

Comment: what errors console says?

Comment: It looks like all of those should work with the posted markup, so something else is wrong -> https://jsfiddle.net/3ooaagj6/

Comment: Is your select element created dynamically e.g. ajax call ?

Comment: It is created on the html view (codeigniter framework). I have just noticed that there is this error which might be causing the problem: Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Comment: This error means that you must load JQuery script first. please make your `<script src='/path/to/jquery.js'/>` first tag after `<head>`

Comment: Thank you. It has fixed the jQuery error. Testing out the other answers now.

Comment: your code should work, be sure its loaded after page has full loaded `$(document).ready(function(){...Code...});` and there is `.on("change",function(){.....})` to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understood correctly, you want the index of the `select` and not the one of the selected `option`.

In that case you have to look at `$(this).attr('name')` and extract the index from that string.

Alternatively you could add a `data` attribute to the selects with only the index, which is easier to retrieve than extracting it from the name.

I made an example on how to do both.

Also be sure if the selects are included via Ajax, you can't use `.bind` or `.change` but [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

```js
$('select').change(function(){
  alert(
    'Select name index: ' + $(this).attr('name').replace(/pricing\[(\d+)\]/, '$1') + 
    '\nSelect data index: ' + $(this).data('index') + 
    '\nValue: ' + $(this).val()
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="pricing[1]" data-index="1">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1-1">1-1</option>
  <option value="1-2">1-2</option>
</select>
<select name="pricing[2]" data-index="2">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="2-1">2-1</option>
  <option value="2-2">2-2</option>
</select>
<select name="pricing[3]" data-index="3">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="3-1">3-1</option>
  <option value="3-2">3-2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The `$(this).attr('name')` and the `replace` function is what I was looking for. I could now manipulate the data. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` to get the selected option from the `select` and use `index` to get the index of the option.

```
 console.log($(this).find('option:selected').index())
```

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  console.log(
    'Name: ',this.name,
    'Value: ',this.value,
    'Index: ',$(this).find('option:selected').index()
  )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="pricing[1]">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select name="pricing[2]">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select name="pricing[3]">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: He most certainly does. There's more than one `select` and using context makes sure it doesn't select **all** the options in the document, but only the ones inside the current select.

Comment: Thank you so much. The codes worked and are really helpful. I will just have to mark the other one as the answer since my question was how to retrieve the index within the name.

Comment: @Maranatha No issues :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $("#dropdownexample")**.prop('selectedIndex')**

Ie:
Html

```
<select id="dropdownexample">
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no" selected="selected">No</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
alert($("#dropdownexample").prop('selectedIndex'));
```

I have tried this and it seems to work.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I believe this is for getting the index of the selected value, right? What I am trying to get is the index within the name of the dropdown. For example, I have a dropdown named "pricing[1]", I will get the index there which is 1. Also, I am still unsure where to implement that because I cannot access the OnChange function of the dropdowns.